# Tweaking transition speed for slider in Andromeda theme for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, themes, slider

I need to slow down the transition for my slide slow in the Andromeda theme.  I have searched far and wide, and can't seem to find where to do this.

I believe Andromeda uses the Nivo slider, and was included in the theme module.

Answer (score 0):

Using Drupal's Admin menu, navigate to Structure > Views. On the View list page, click on the Edit link for the Image Slideshow. On the Image Slideshow Edit page (`admin/structure/views/view/image_slideshow/edit`), click on the Settings link for Format: Views Nivo Slider.

[image: Image Slideshow Edit page]

On the Settings pop-up, edit the Animation Speed value to slow down the slide transition.
[image: Views Nivo Slider Settings]

Comment: I don't have a menu point "Views" under "Structure" - is tht an additional module?

Thanks!
Ron